# Issue with javascript validation in Selenium webdriver c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to validate if a jstree has loaded in the UI before I run a selenium command to click a node in the tree, my issue is with writing the javascript validation in the c# code, any advice ?

```
class Hello
{


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IWebDriver Chrome = new ChromeDriver();

        Chrome.Url = "http://localhost:60268/Login.aspx";


        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName']")).SendKeys("chinthaka");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_Password']")).SendKeys("Welkom123456");

        Chrome.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton")).Click();



        // Rather than checking for the specific element with an explicit wait I have used an implecit wait to poll the dom until all elements have been loaded




       Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_toppanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_toppanelcontent']//div[@title='Add a new relation aa']")).Click();


        //add record
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]//input[@name='15986B36-838D-4F44-A7C7-04B2AFCA042F']")).SendKeys("MR");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]//input[@name='91D3E3C9-70C1-47B0-A125-FAAFBCA3C923']")).SendKeys("LOCAL ");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]//input[@name='963F62CE-0C57-435C-AEA8-CE912CA0BFFC']")).SendKeys("DUDE ");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]//input[@name='C360F8E7-D427-4067-A1E9-34C8644CCD2C']")).SendKeys("PLAIN");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(" //div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]//input[@name='54EF9BEA-1AD3-4CCD-893C-291CEA82A561']")).SendKeys("SIMPLE");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]//input[@name='3015E3A7-13BC-44FB-9844-A12B83F58D40']")).SendKeys("PLAIN@ymail.com");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[6]/tbody/tr[@class='H2Row']//table[@class='H2Table']//tr[@class='H2Row']/td[2]//input[@name='B3BF78C4-0833-466B-B8F3-85AFA812A4A2']")).SendKeys("jj@ymail.com");



        //Drop down
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".row > .H2Table:nth-child(2) .H2Row:nth-of-type(1) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();
        //[ng-controller] .row > .H2Table:nth-child(2) .H2Row:nth-of-type(1) .chosen-single

        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Row:nth-of-type(9) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Row:nth-of-type(13) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();

        // calendar
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Table:nth-child(3) [src]")).Click();
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Table:nth-child(4) [src]")).Click();


        //save record

        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='H2ReactMainToolStripContainer']//div[@title='Save']/img[@src='App_Themes/H2React/Icons/Actions-document-save-icon.png']")).Click();

        //pop up

        new WebDriverWait(Chrome, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//body[@class='ng-scope']/div[@role='dialog']//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[1]/span[@class='ui-button-text']"))).Click();


        //  new WebDriverWait(Chrome, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//*[@id='R3Tree']")));


        JsTree();


        Chrome.FindElement(By.LinkText("Address1"));



        // Close(Chrome);
        //*[@id="13cb117e-2c1e-4262-beaf-24af6ed269e3"]/a/text()

    }


    //The idea is to make the html page run which contains the javascript code which will check if the Jstree is loaded

    public static Action JsTree()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("");



        return null;
    }
```

I am calling the tstree validation before I click the link text element "Address1" gregregregregregregregre

Comment: Why dont you record the GUI Test using Selenium IDE that's a plugin for FireFox. It has all these  exporting to code options, including to C# code.

Comment: My issue is running the javascript validation that is all I need to make sure the tree is loaded , because without it I cannot click the tree node with my selenium code.

Comment: Show us your code? A [MCVE] would be good, I know you're new here so please give this a read: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Have a look please ,I have added the code I am using

Comment: When I use Selenium or Awesomium I run all my code as JavaScript injected that returns a response object. It's sad, but I find the server side api to be very weak and buggy. Good luck.

Comment: So if I am to go on the client side of things do I use selenium web driver ?